# Using multiple Fn::Sub inside Fn::if

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Currently trying to use an Fn::if with multiple Fn::Subs, however currently only the first is converted. I tried using multiple methods to create this, however this is the only method I was able to produce without causing syntax error's.

```
Resource:
 - !Sub arn:aws:ecr:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:repository/reponame
 - !Sub arn:aws:ecr:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:repository/reponame
 - !Sub arn:aws:ecr:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:repository/reponame
 - !Sub arn:aws:ecr:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:repository/reponame
 - Fn::If:
   - USRegion
   - !Sub arn:aws:ecr:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:repository/reponame
     !Sub arn:aws:ecr:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:repository/reponame
     !Sub arn:aws:ecr:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:repository/reponame
     !Sub arn:aws:ecr:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:repository/reponame
   - !Ref AWS::NoValue
```

Tried using

```
Resource:
 - !Sub arn:aws:ecr:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:repository/reponame
 - !Sub arn:aws:ecr:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:repository/reponame
 - !Sub arn:aws:ecr:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:repository/reponame
 - !Sub arn:aws:ecr:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:repository/reponame
 - Fn::If:
   - USRegion
   - - !Sub arn:aws:ecr:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:repository/reponame
     - !Sub arn:aws:ecr:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:repository/reponame
     - !Sub arn:aws:ecr:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:repository/reponame
     - !Sub arn:aws:ecr:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:repository/reponame
   - !Ref AWS::NoValue
```

which I saw in another SO question but still no dice.

How do I go about changing this to convert each value, rather than only the first?

Edit: For context here I've added that there is multiple arn's that aren't apart of the if statement.

Two current best solutions I have found

```
 - !Sub arn:aws:ecr:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:repository/reponame3
 - !Sub arn:aws:ecr:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:repository/reponame4
 - !Sub arn:aws:ecr:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:repository/reponame5
 - Fn::If:
   - USRegion
   - !Sub arn:aws:ecr:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:repository/reponame1
   - !Ref AWS::NoValue
 - Fn::If:
   - USRegion
   - !Sub arn:aws:ecr:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:repository/reponame2
   - !Ref AWS::NoValue
```

Or

```
  Fn::If:
   - USRegion
   - - !Sub arn:aws:ecr:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:repository/reponame1
     - !Sub arn:aws:ecr:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:repository/reponame2
     - !Sub arn:aws:ecr:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:repository/reponame3
     - !Sub arn:aws:ecr:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:repository/reponame4
     - !Sub arn:aws:ecr:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:repository/reponame5
   - - !Sub arn:aws:ecr:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:repository/reponame3
     - !Sub arn:aws:ecr:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:repository/reponame4
     - !Sub arn:aws:ecr:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:repository/reponame5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should be (be careful about indentations):

```
Resource:
  Fn::If:
    - USRegion
    - - !Sub arn:aws:ecr:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:repository/reponame
      - !Sub arn:aws:ecr:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:repository/reponame
      - !Sub arn:aws:ecr:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:repository/reponame
      - !Sub arn:aws:ecr:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:repository/reponame
    - !Ref AWS::NoValue
```

Here if the `USRegion` is true, you return a list. In your original attempt you wanted to create a list of lists.

But you would need to reconsider using  `AWS::NoValue`, assuming this is some IAM policy. `Resource` is [required](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_resource.html) in an IAM policy statement, so you can't make IAM policy without a resource, in cases where `USRegion` is false.

Comment: This seems to solve this in regards to a single list but if you have additional list items outside  the "if" statement you will receive an error. Only solution I have found in this context is just include your constants (resources that stay the same) on both side of the statement, or limit your if statement to a single list item (seems to be no way to add to an upper level list).

Comment: @ION Thanks, and yes, you can't mixed lists. Thanks for letting me know. Glad it worked out:-)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are generating an IAM policy. Your second attempt is producting a result like this with a list inside a list.

```
Resource:
 - - arn1
   - arn2
   - arn3
   - arn4
```

Your template should look like this:

```
 Resource:
   "Fn::If":
     - USRegion
     - !Sub arn:aws:ecr:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:repository/reponame
       !Sub arn:aws:ecr:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:repository/reponame
       !Sub arn:aws:ecr:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:repository/reponame
       !Sub arn:aws:ecr:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:repository/reponame
     - []
```

Or if you can't have the Resource set to an empty array, move the if statement higher so the whole policy statement is generated.

Comment: Sadly this is incorrect without "- Fn::If:" I just receive a "YAML not well-formed".

Comment: Ah the Fn::If needs to be in quotes. Edited.

Comment: Sadly this just produces the same result as my original question, it creates a single list item with all 4 lines inside, instead of 4 list items. The answer below is the closest that is correct.